# What's the best way to have svn:eol-style=native for text files by default?

Tags: svn

I find that it is best practice to have all text files have `svn:eol-style=native` property set. But what's the most efficient way to do it?

I develop programs mainly on Windows(using TortoiseSVN and `svn.exe` command line) and sometimes write portable C/C++ libraries for Windows and Linux. In order to prevent the nasty mix-CR,LF problem on my source files, I think `svn:eol-style=native` should be the "default", but unfortunately it is not.

I know from Subversion Red Book that configuring `[auto-props]` in `~/.subversion/config` or `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` helps, however, it is per client setting. What about some developer in my team forget to configure those config files (think about dev on multiple virtual machines)? Even all do remember, what if some new kind of text file extension-name occurs? How do I properly propagate this change to all config file on all dev machines in my team?

All seems to be a cumbersome process.

Comment: Related: [Force svn:eol-style=native on the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671406/force-svneol-style-native-on-the-server)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Subversion 1.8 way**

Because Subversion 1.8 got [repository dictated configuration](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/the-road-to-repository-dictated-configuration-day-2-autoprops) (RDC), for **mandatory** using common settings by **all** clients for a given repository, property can and have to be configured in the repository root (or trunk)

Comment: Thank you. That solution by svn 1.8 is brilliant which I think solves 99% of the hassle.

Answer (score 22):

> What about some developer in my team forget to configure those config
>   files(think about dev on multiple virtual machines)?

Just fix error.

If you find a file that was incorrectly checked in, it's not too hard to fix.
First, change the file to the correct line-ending style for your platform. Any programming editor should be able to switch styles with some built-in command, or you can use a 'fromdos' or 'todos'-type utility.
Once it's fixed, set the property and check it in:

```
 svn propset svn:eol-style native filename
 svn commit filename
```

Copy of my comment:

Another suggestion is to use pre-commit hook, check svn:eol-style settings (and presence) and fix if needed

Comment: Another suggestion is to use pre-commit hook, check svn:eol-style settings (and presence) and fix if needed

Comment: May be a good idea. Can pre-commit hook silently add svn:eol-style=native property to committed file just before committing to the repository? When svn client does 'svn update' next time, he gets that property automatically.

Comment: I think - it can: you can use any commands in hook-script. I don't kbow only how to get file-list for files in commit and single file from list

Comment: Until svn 1.7, I have to confess installing a pre-commit hook is the most viable way. Please COPY your first comment to your answer body and I'll mark it accepted. Thanks. BTW: "get file list" of a commit is easy with svnlook.exe , so there is no techninal barrier now.

Answer (score 9):

This should be a quick answer, not "dive into details and get it yourself, here is the link" version.

**We'll just f-ing do it, okay?** For subversion 1.8+:

```
$ cd my_checkout_dir

$ svn propset svn:auto-props '
### src
*.c = svn:eol-style=native
*.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
*.h = svn:eol-style=native
*.pch = svn:eol-style=native
*.lua = svn:eol-style=native
*.py = svn:eol-style=native
*.pl = svn:eol-style=native
*.txt = svn:eol-style=native
*.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
### ui
*.xib = svn:eol-style=native
*.ui = svn:eol-style=native
*.qrc = svn:eol-style=native
### project
*.pro = svn:eol-style=native
*.pbxproj = svn:eol-style=native
*.json = svn:eol-style=native
*.xcworkspacedata = svn:eol-style=native
*.plist = svn:eol-style=native
' .

$ svn commit -m 'Got really tired of svn:eol-style issues'
```

Please note closing single-quote and dot (i.e. current dir) at the end. Tune this list for your needs, copy `svn propset svn:auto-props '…' .` into unix/msys sh-terminal (yes, with Enters). After commit, all files below `my_checkout_dir` will inherit corresponding properties upon add. Files **added before** this action will **not** be modified. As you see in `*.sh` and below, you can add more properties via `;`. If you want to change the list, just repeat everything again.

Here are defaults suggested by svn in my `~/.subversion/config` for the reference:

```
### The format of the entries is:
###   file-name-pattern = propname[=value][;propname[=value]...]
### The file-name-pattern can contain wildcards (such as '*' and
### '?').  All entries which match (case-insensitively) will be
### applied to the file.  Note that auto-props functionality
### must be enabled, which is typically done by setting the
### 'enable-auto-props' option.
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
# *.h = svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;svn:eol-style=native
# *.dsp = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.dsw = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
# *.txt = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;
# *.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
# *.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg
# Makefile = svn:eol-style=native
```